# apex_string.split new line as delimiter

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using this query to split a string of a text area field inside my SQL query:

```
select * from "MyTable" a 
where NAME in (select * from 
TABLE(apex_string.split(:P23_TEXTAREA, ',')))
```

It works but I would like to split the string with a new line delimiter instead of a comma. I tried already "\n", "\r\n", "
" but without success. If I remove the delimiter and use the default, the string gets split only once with a new line. How can I split my string with multiple new line separated entries?

Comment: What is the output of `select DUMP(:P23_TEXTAREA) from dual`? The default should split by newlines and so should `\n` but if your text only has a single new line character then you will only get two values output.

Comment: It reports Typ=1 Len=16: 84,82,73,95,49,48,48,48,13,10,84,82,73,95,49,48 with two lines

Comment: That only has one character with an ASCII value of 10 so you should end up with 2 values in the collection after splitting.

Comment: I don't understand, with comma or semicolon it works as expected but for the new line it reports only the last value, even if I add another new line https://imgur.com/a/yQs1oA0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `CHR` function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(apex_string.split(:P23_TEXTAREA, CHR(10)))
```

or a string literal containing a newline:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(apex_string.split(:P23_TEXTAREA, '
'))
```

---

Your `:P23_TEXTAREA` value is: `'TRI_1000'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)||'TRI_10'` which, if you split it on `CHR(10)` (LF) will give you the values `'TRI_1000'||CHR(13)` and `'TRI_10'` and the second will probably match but the first will not due to the trailing carriage return (CR) character.

It appears you need to either trim the result or split on CR/LF (or an optional CR) rather than just LF:

```
SELECT *
FROM   "MyTable"
WHERE  name IN (SELECT * 
                FROM   TABLE(apex_string.split(:P23_TEXTAREA, '\r?\n'))
               )
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM   "MyTable"
WHERE  name IN (SELECT RTRIM(COLUMN_VALUE, CHR(13)) 
                FROM   TABLE(apex_string.split(:P23_TEXTAREA, CHR(10)))
               )
```

Comment: Both return only the last value from the split string (as the default).

Comment: I updated the sql query, if I insert two IDs with new line, it will report only the last entry.

Comment: @honeymoon Updated - you need to deal with the carriage return character as well as splitting on the line feed character.

Comment: The second version works, first one does not return any value when using more then one line. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The default delimiter for `apex_string.split` is LF (line feed) so one way to do this is to replace the CR+LF combos with a single LF before passing it to split:

```
select * from "MyTable" a 
where NAME in (select * from 
    TABLE(apex_string.split(
        replace(:P23_TEXTAREA, chr(13)||chr(10), chr(10))
    ))
)
```